# Indicar el tamaño de un Arreglo por consola

Tags: java, array

Tengo este código, por el momento solo tengo declarado el arreglo de 5 posiciones, de ahí por medio de la consola se le dan valores al arreglo
 y lo despliega ( [1,2,3,4,5] ) por ejemplo.

Ahora quiero que el tamaño del arreglo, se introduzca por consola lo intente en `obtenerDimension` guardando tal valor en una variable n pero no sé como declarar el arreglo principal que es `numeros1[]`

pd. no hagan mucho caso a las partes comentadas.

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arreglo9
{

    private int numeros1[]; // = new int[3];
    private int contador[];
/// private int numeros2[];


    public Arreglo9()
    {
    contador = new int[5];          
    }

    private void obtenerDimension(int numm) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isrV = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader brV = new BufferedReader(isrV);

        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor del arreglo");
        String s2=brV.readLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        numeros1[] = new int [n];   
    } 

    private void obtenerDatos( int nums[]) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("Ingresa el arreglo");

            for(int i =0; i<nums.length;i++)
                {
                    String s1 = br.readLine();
                    int x= Integer.parseInt(s1);
                    nums[i]=x;
                //  nums[i]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numeros["+i+"] ="));
                }

            int total=0;
            System.out.println("Arreglo: ");                    
    } 

    private void desplegarDatos(int numbers[])
    {
        String str="[";
        int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<numbers.length-1;i++)
            str = str + numbers[i] + ",";       
            str = str +numbers[i] + "]";
            System.out.println(str);

    }

    private void principal() throws IOException
    {
        obtenerDimension(numeros1);
        obtenerDatos(numeros1);
        obtener(numeros1);
        desplegarDatos(numeros1);   

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Arreglo9 objeto = new Arreglo9();
    //  int numeros[] = new int[3];     
        objeto.principal();
    }
}
```

Comment: De cual arreglo quieres que se muestre la dimensión o cantidad de datos en la consola?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez de numeros1

Comment: console.log(numeros1.length().toString) prueba eso

Comment: mmm tal vez no me explique pero el numero ya lo captura. Tengo problema con el arreglo, no se como declararlo por así decirlo.

Comment: Un arreglo integer "int arreglo[]= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"

Comment: Si quieres ponerle un tamaño definido al arreglo "int arreglo[5];" el numero lo puedes cambiar por una variable integer.

Comment: Podrías reducir tu código un poco? La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: no pude quitar mas, es necesario para entender el funcionamiento del resto, creo yo

Comment: Para hacer lo que quieres lo que te falta es declarar el arreglo numeros1 fuera del main oara hacerlo una variable global. Así le podrás dar tamaño desde una función y rellenarlo desde otra.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano lo tengo declarado como private int numeros1[]; y lo relleno en obtenerDimension, pero ahí es donde tengo problemas.

Answer (score 1):

entiendo que quieres trabajar la longitud de tu arreglo de manera dinámica.

Podrías trabajar de la siguiente manera.

```
public class Arreglo9{

private int tamanio;
private int numeros1[];
private int contador[];

public Arreglo9(int tamanio){
       this.tamanio = tamanio;
       numeros1 = new int[tamanio];
       contador = new int[tamanio];
}


public static void main(Strin args[]){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo");
       int tamanio = sc.nextInt();

       Arreglo9 objeto = new Arreglo9(tamanio);
       objeto.principal();
}
```

Espero que esta haya sido la duda, en tal caso, me la haces saber. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No se puede crear un array sin saber de antemano cuántos elementos va a contener, porque va contra la definición de array.

Entonces, lo que deberías hacer es usar [listas](https://jarroba.com/arraylist-en-java-ejemplos/), que es lo conceptualmente correcto. En Java, una de las implementaciones más usadas es [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), que internamente trabaja con un array. Para crear una lista de números y agregar valores deberías escribir algo como esto:

```
List<int> listaNumeros = new ArrayList<int>();
// Agregar elementos a la lista
listaNumeros.add(28);
// Consultar cuántos elementos tiene
listaNumeros.size() // en este caso, devolvería 1
```

Si tenés que sí o sí usar arrays, se me ocurre que podrías inicializar un array con un número que sepas que es grande para tu problema (por ejemplo, 1000) y luego solo usar la parte que necesites. Pero esto no es más que un hack, lo que corresponde para un problema así es usar una lista.

Comment: Si se puede crear un array sin darle longitud. Aunque esté de acuerdo contigo en que si no sabes la cantidad de elementos es preferible utilizar listas, es posible crear un array y darle el tamaño después desde código. No es recomendable reservar 1000 posiciones (por ejemplo) ya que estamos reservando memoria que no vamos a utilizar.

Comment: ¿Podés dar un ejemplo de cómo se hace? Yo estoy bastante seguro de que no se puede.

Comment: Pues hay que hacer lo que ha hecho el compañero @ChristhianSandovalChauca en su respuesta. Declarar la variable como global y luego le das el tamaño. Lo acabo de probar y funciona sin problemas.